# All this time or All these time?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english, speech, grammaticality

My sentence flow is something like this. "So you were lying to me all these time?" I dont know if I should use this or these.

Comment: It'd be "this time".

Comment: Could you Ask about specific "sentence flows", rather than "something like…"?

Either way, "all these time…" will always be wrong and "all this time…" correct

Why though? What makes you uncertain at all?

What makes you think such Questions belong here rather than, for instance, at English Language Learners?

Answer (score 3):

"All this time" is appropriate for a current situation.  If the actions were in the past, then the statement should be "all that time" or "all those/these times."  The variants are dependent upon your personal view or understanding of time itself.

Answer (score -1):

All that time - during that period.

All these times - on each of those occasions.

Comment: Or _All this time_  - during a long period until now.